# Rotate a bundle of absolute positioned divs - <edited> without putting them in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to rotate divs , but each div gets rotated "alone" , i wish to rotate them as a "team".

How can i rotate the divs so they wiil stay aligned ? like they were in the beginning?

This is what i managed to do so far , but each card has same height..

```js
function rotateme() {

  $(".card").addClass("rotateme");

}
```

```css
.card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45px;
    height: 70px;
    top:120px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: solid black;
}

#card0 {
  left:104;
}

#card1 {
  left: 124px;
}

#card2 {
  left: 144px;
}


#card3 {
  left : 164px;
}

.rotateme {

 transform: rotate(20deg);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="rotateme()">PRESS ME</button>
 <div class="card" id="card1"></div>
 <div class="card" id="card2"></div>
 <div class="card" id="card3"></div>
```

Comment: You can put all cards in a container and rotate the container, or you can calculate the `transform-origin` for each card to be on the same point in your document.

Comment: how can i do the last , putting in a container is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in another div and rotate this instead like so:

```js
function rotateme() {

  $(".cards").addClass("rotateme");

}
```

```css
.card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45px;
    height: 70px;
    top:120px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: solid black;
}

#card0 {
  left:104;
}

#card1 {
  left: 124px;
}

#card2 {
  left: 144px;
}


#card3 {
  left : 164px;
}

.rotateme {

 transform: rotate(20deg);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="rotateme()">PRESS ME</button>
<div class="cards">
 <div class="card" id="card1"></div>
 <div class="card" id="card2"></div>
 <div class="card" id="card3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks , how can them stay on the same place when rotated? 
in your snippet they "jump" left

Comment: You will need to set [``transform-origin``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) on the ``cards`` container and experiment with the values